# Is it possible to redirect user to another form depending on values entered in the first form

Tags: webforms, redirection, rules

I have 3 Webforms named A, AA and AB, In form A there are few question with Yes and No options.

I am looking for a way to direct user depending on the selected options, If user select all the options as Yes and press submit the form should direct the user to form AA else to form AB.

Is there any easy way/Module to check the Form A and direct user to either AA or AB depending on the selected options

I assume rules could be a choice, but i can't figure out.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but in [Multistep Form](https://www.drupal.org/node/324779) created with Webform module, wasn't empty pages simply skipped? And wasn't you able to make fields dependant on fields from earlier page, to be hidden if previous choice made them not needed? With [right module](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_conditional) you don't even need multiple pages, but that's pretty much outside of the scope of your question.

Comment: @Mołot Thank you very much for the help, current version of Webform comes with coeducation tab which could be use to provide condition both in the same page and in other page. I am not sure why would someone use right module.

Comment: My case, In order to complete the survey user need to meet our requirements. therefore i have would like to have a page with 10 question and if they answer yes to all the questions then only they should access the survey. if the user doesn't meet our requirements then I want to display a message once user click submit because I want to save the user respond and find out which question was answered as No

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I Manage to redirect user to anther form base on entered values.

1. Install [Rules module](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) and [Webform Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_rules)
2. Create new rule
3. From React on event select After a submission draft has been submitted
4. Add a new condition, select Webform has name, Select form_id from Data selector, and select the form name from Weforms value
5. Add a new condition select Execute custom PHP code
6. Add the custom code

   if ($data['components']['1_are_you_aged_18_to_50_years_of_age_']['value'][0]=='Yes')  {
   return TRUE;
   } else {
   return FALSE;
   }

Change the field name 1_are_you_aged_18_to_50_years_of_age_' and Yes value to your own field name and value
 7. Add an action, select Page redirect and add the URL.

8. Click save, And click save again.
9. Go to /people/permissions
10. Allow all the user type to Execute PHP code "Please note allowing users to execute PHP code is not recommended due to security risk".

Comment: I can't believe that webform rules doesn't allow you to select webform components in the data selector and the only way to get it to work is to enable the dangerous PHP filter.

Comment: @nexus_6 There is anther module https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_rules which extend the functionality of rules but not sure how much it help.

Comment: that's the module I'm talking about. It doesn't make it easy to compare the values of form components with the rules data selector: you have to do it in PHP.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I only had to change `After a submission draft has been submitted` to `After a webform has been submitted`.  For the PHP code, a simpler version would be `return $data['components']['1_are_you_aged_18_to_50_years_of_age_']['value'][0]=='Yes';`

Answer (score 0):

Yama gets close, but, instead of using custom PHP in your rule, [try this patch to  the webform_rules](https://www.drupal.org/node/2020149) module that exposes form data that's been submitted directly to the rules UI, without requiring you to write custom PHP code.

More importantly, step 10 in the answer from Yama creates a potentially serious security problem on your site.  They aren't kidding when they say "Please note allowing users to execute PHP code is not recommended due to security risk".  It is a permission that should never be granted to anonymous or untrusted users.